# How can I write this equivalent code using gocolly

Tags: go, web, web-scraping

I try to use `https://github.com/gocolly/colly.` I try to visit a URL and save the full response on my local disc for example visit google.com and save the full response body of the URL google.html.

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="bn"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-;google.pmc=JSON.parse(pmc);})();</script>        </body></html>
```

```golang
func main() {
    response, err := http.Get("https://www.google.com")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    outFile, err := os.Create("google.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer outFile.Close()

    // Copy data from HTTP response to file
    _, err = io.Copy(outFile, response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

My expected output:

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="bn"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-;google.pmc=JSON.parse(pmc);})();</script>        </body></html>
```

Comment: OK, so what is happening? I ran your code locally, it all worked perfectly fine for me, although the output is a bit more than what you're expecting, it's still the markup for the page.

Comment: And I do not see any usage of colly in the code.